# Kotlin split string in the last space

Tags: kotlin

I have a String and i want to split it , and drop the last part .

For example something like that for this input :

```
var example = "Long string to split in the last space"
```

I want to achieve  this result

```
var result = "Long string to split in the last"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`substringBeforeLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before-last.html):

```
"Long string to split in the last space".substringBeforeLast(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

A more verbose alternative to **[substringBeforeLast](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before-last.html)** that works for removing the last `n` words by using **[dropLast](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop-last.html)**:

```
var example = "Long string to split in the last space"
var result = example.split(" ")
                    .dropLast(1)
                    .joinToString(" ")
println(result) // Long string to split in the last
```

Comment: Not only more verbose, but much slower.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Would you recommend I delete my answer, so I don't confuse people searching? I just thought that substringBeforeLast has no way of deleting the last `n` words. Which might be a common extension to this question.

Comment: I wouldn't, so far as drawbacks are clear. I actually didn't notice that you mention last n words.